# Is it possible to put lambda expressions into a map or list in C++?

Tags: c++

@DanielLangr @luxun @cdhowie Sorry for the XY problem. I am not sure I can explain well, but I'll try my best. The situation is almost like this: there is a base class `Worker` and some children (`Chef`, `Tailor`, ...). Children have the same actions (walk, run, sleep, ...) but different skills. `Chef` can make food, `Tailor` can make clothes. An invoker calls `Worker::dothings()` but does not exactly know their profession. So I add an interface `dothings(Thing)` on the `Worker` base object. `Thing` is an `enum` (values `MakeFood`, `MakeClothes`, ...).

```
Worker *w = new Chef();
w->dothings(MakeFood);
w->dothings(MakeClothes);  // throw exception "w does not have the skill"
```

I'm thinking to maybe use a container in children that describes what they can do and how to do it.

I want to put different lambda expressions into a list or a `QMap`:

```
QMap<String, lambda> map;
map.insert("first", [](int i) -> int {return i;});
map.insert("second", [](string s) -> string {return s;});
```

Is it possible in C++? And what is the type of a lambda? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't think the above example will work as the lambdas above will have different types: one returns a string and the other returns an int.

Comment: What is `Qmap`? Likely it's not possible, but you should be able to store lambda to containers with help of `std::function`. Just note that all these functions mush have compatible signatures.

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910). Back up a bit, forget about lambdas, functions, and maps -- what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Based on the recent edit I think we are getting somewhere :) one way to achieve what you are attempting is to do away with the map of lambdas, and have virtual functions for all the types of task (make food, make clothes etc) on the base class. The base class implementations could throw an exception, then it's up to the subclasses to define which functions should be overridden. There might be a better way depending on your broader context, so you may want to elaborate on this, but would satisfy the immediate requirement.

Comment: What do you do with the result of `map["first"](10)`? What happens when someone calls `map["second"](10)`? What decides between `"first"` and `"second"`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible but using [function wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

For example,

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string)>> my_map;
my_map.emplace("first", [](std::string i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; });
```

However, if you want to pass any type of argument to your function and return any type from your lambda/function, use [boost::any](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any.html). You also use [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) if you are using `C++17` or above.

**EDIT:**

A working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main()
{
    auto any = [](boost::any i)
    {
        std::cout << "In any" << std::endl;
        if (i.type() == typeid(int))
            std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(i) << std::endl;
        return boost::any(1000);
    };
    std::map<std::string, std::function<boost::any(boost::any)>> my_map;
    my_map.emplace("first", any);
    my_map.emplace("second", [](boost::any i) -> boost::any { });
    auto ret = my_map["first"](100);
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(ret) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
In any
100
1000
```

Comment: my problem is the lambda i put into map may have different return type.so i don't think std::function can help.
if i use boost::any, what kind of type shoud i use in boost::any_cast<type>?

Comment: @miniboxHaHa What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: For different return types, you can return boost::any.

Comment: @abhiarora i think you were right.i will try it on my code.thanks

Comment: Using `any` is a bit pointless as there is no good way to interact with the value afterwards, as you would need to know all candidate-types you are interested in.

Comment: I agree but I am assuming the OP knows about the possible types passed to the expression.

Comment: @miniboxHaHa: Sure! Happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

It is *possible* as long as you are trying to insert the same lambda type ( your example has different lambda types) You have to be careful how you do it but it does work. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


int main(){
    auto factory = [](int i){
        return [=](int j){return i+j;};
    };

    using L = decltype(factory(0));

    std::map<int,L> map;

    map.emplace(0,factory(0));
    map.emplace(7,factory(7));
    std::cout << map.at(0)(3) << std::endl ;
    std::cout << map.at(7)(3) << std::endl ;

}
```

outputs

```
3
10
```

as expected and not a `std::function` in sight! However the following does not work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


int main(){
    auto factory = [](int i){
        return [=](int j){return i+j;};
    };

    using L = decltype(factory(0));

    std::map<int,L> map;

    map[0]=factory(0);
    map[7]=factory(7);
    std::cout << map[0](3) << std::endl ;
    std::cout << map[7](3) << std::endl ;

}
```

Using the indexing operator tries to use copy assignment whereas emplace doesn't.

https://godbolt.org/z/co1vno6xb

Answer (score 3):

With `any`, the solution may look like as follows:

```
auto lambda1 = [](int i) { return i; };
auto lambda2 = [](std::string s) { return s; };

std::map<std::string, std::any> map;
map["first"] = lambda1;
map["second"] = lambda2;

std::cout << std::any_cast<decltype(lambda1)>(map["first"])(-1) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::any_cast<decltype(lambda2)>(map["second"])("hello") << std::endl;
```

I am not familiar with `Qmap` and `String`, so I used the types from the C++ Standard Library.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/8XK8de

---

Alternatively, you can also additionally use `std::function` if you want to avoid those `decltype`s:

```
std::map<std::string, std::any> map;
map["first"] = std::function<int(int)>( [](int i) { return i; } );
map["second"] = std::function<std::string(std::string)>( [](std::string s) { return s; } );

std::cout << std::any_cast<std::function<int(int)>>(map["first"])(-1) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::any_cast<std::function<std::string(std::string)>>(map["second"])("hello") << std::endl
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/XAc3Q2

---

However, as other pointed out to, this really seems to be an *XY problem*.

Comment: i think you were right.i will try it on my code.thanks!

Comment: Using `any` is a bit pointless as there is no good way to interact with the value afterwards, as you would need to know all candidate-types you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

#### For future searchers

I believe the most straightforward answer would look like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<const std::string, std::function<void()>> factory{
      {"apple", [](){ std::cout << "Sayas Apple\n"; }},
      {"banana", [](){ std::cout << "Sayas Banana\n"; }}
      };

    std::string keys[] = {"apple", "apple", "banana", "apple", "banana", "banana"};

    for(std::string key : keys)
    {
        factory[key]();
    }

    return 0;

};
```

#### [My answer mostly comes from this article](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/functional-in-c-dispatch-table/)

Comment: What happens if key does not exist?  Will this throw?  I think it is supposed to create a new element for the [] operator, but I am not sure what happens when you try to use the lambda.  Lambdas don't have default constructors.  Maybe it is safer with the at() which has bound checking.