# Way to reduce else if statements when using string as condition

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I'm making a terminal-like program (to calculate currency) with custom commands as input but I have a problem.
Every time I implement a new command, I have to add a new `else if` statement. This wouldn't be a problem but for a terminal-like program there can be a lot of commands.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>

float user_balance = 0.0f;
float eur_in_czk = 24.0f;   //ammount of czk in single euro
std::string currency = "czk";
bool czk_to_eur_enabled = true;
bool eur_to_czk_enabled = false;

//------------------START method definition---------------------------------------------------------
void czk_to_eur()
{
    if (czk_to_eur_enabled) //to prevent using twice in a row
    {
        user_balance /= eur_in_czk;
        user_balance = floorf(user_balance * 100) / 100;    //limit to two decimal numbers
        currency = "eur";
        czk_to_eur_enabled = false;
        eur_to_czk_enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your savings are already converted to  " << currency << "!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void eur_to_czk()
{
    if (eur_to_czk_enabled) //to prevent using twice in a row
    {
        user_balance *= eur_in_czk;
        user_balance = floorf(user_balance * 100) / 100;    //limit to two decimal numbers
        currency = "czk";
        eur_to_czk_enabled = false;
        czk_to_eur_enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your savings are already converted to " << currency << "!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void set_balance(float new_balance)
{
    user_balance = new_balance;
}

void add_balance(float new_balance)
{
    user_balance += new_balance;
}
//------------------END method definition-----------------------------------------------------------


int main()
{
    bool main_loop = true;  //main loop enabler
    float input_money;
    std::string user_command = "";

    std::cout << "This is currency converter v1.0 (czk to eur and back)\n\n\n" << std::endl;

    while (main_loop)   //main loop for currency converter
    {
        std::cout << "Input: ";
        std::cin >> user_command;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        if ((user_command == "setbal") || (user_command == "SETBAL"))
        {
            std::cout << "Your balance is " << user_balance << " " << currency << ".\n";
            std::cout << "Please enter desired value (" << currency << "): ";
            std::cin >> input_money;
            set_balance(input_money);
            std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else if ((user_command == "addbal") || (user_command == "ADDBAL"))
        {
            std::cout << "Your balance is " << user_balance << " " << currency << ".\n";
            std::cout << "Please enter desired value (" << currency << "): ";
            std::cin >> input_money;
            add_balance(input_money);
            std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else if ((user_command == "balance") || (user_command == "BALANCE"))
        {
            std::cout << "Your balance is " << user_balance << " " << currency << "." << std::endl;
        }
        else if ((user_command == "curstat") || (user_command == "CURSTAT"))
        {
            std::cout << "Currency status is " << eur_in_czk << " czk in 1 eur." << std::endl;
        }
        else if ((user_command == "toeur") || (user_command == "TOEUR"))
        {
            czk_to_eur();
        }
        else if ((user_command == "toczk") || (user_command == "TOCZK"))
        {
            eur_to_czk();
        }
        else if ((user_command == "cheuv") || (user_command == "CHEUV"))
        {
            std::cout << "Change eur value (" << eur_in_czk << "): ";
            std::cin >> eur_in_czk;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else if ((user_command == "help") || (user_command == "HELP"))
        {
            std::cout << "SETBAL        Sets balance.\n"
                      << "ADDBAL        Adds balance.\n"
                      << "BALANCE       Shows current balance.\n"
                      << "CURSTAT       Shows currency status.\n"
                      << "TOEUR         Converts czk to eur.\n"
                      << "TOCZK         Converts eur to czk.\n"
                      << "CHEUV         Changes eur currency value.\n"
                      << "CLS           Cleans terminal history.\n"
                      << "EXIT          Exits program.\n" << std::endl;
        }
        else if ((user_command == "cls") || (user_command == "CLS"))
        {
            system("CLS");  //funtion from Windows.h library
        }
        else if ((user_command == "exit") || (user_command == "EXIT"))
        {
            main_loop = false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "'" << user_command << "'"
                      << "is not recognized as an internal or external command!\n";
            std::cout << "Type 'HELP' to see available commands.\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The bottom part of the code in `while` cycle is where the problem is.

Everything works fine but I would like to know, if there is any other way. And `switch` to my knowledge does not support string values as condition/dependency. (also I'm currently not using any custom classes and/or custom header files because this is just experiment.)

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: ***And switch to my knowledge does not support string values as condition/dependency.*** Correct. You can't switch on a string. You could map the string to an integer or enum and switch on that.

Comment: Here is a different way to do this which is closer to what I would do: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969316/is-it-possible-to-put-lambda-expressions-into-a-map-or-list-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969316/is-it-possible-to-put-lambda-expressions-into-a-map-or-list-in-c)

Comment: Try creating something like a `std::map<std::string, std::function<void()> >` to map strings to a function object (the `void()` indicates accepting no argument and returning `void`, but that can be changed).   Populate that.  If the map is named `your_map` and you want to do an action corresponding to `somestring` then all you need to do is `if (your_map.find(somestring) != your_map.end()) {your_map[somestring]();} else {report_bad_string();}`

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for leply. I used the map and it works as I needed it to. But I had a problem with making multiple values for each key. I found something about multimap but I did it like this: `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>m_commands;` and `m_commands["EXIT"] = { "5", "Exit console." };` as an example. To use it for switch I did this `m_command_id = std::stoi(m_commands.find(m_user_input)->second.at(0));` to select the number 5. I hope it is not a bad implementation of map.
Edit: I forgot that I can add the function directly to it so I will fix that later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I would suggest using a `std::map` with a string as the key and a function as the value so that you could search the map for a command and then invoke the function associated with it. However, since that's already been mentioned in the comments I figured I'd get all fancy and provide **a totally wack solution you probably shouldn't use**.

This wack solution allows you to use string literals in a `switch`/`case` statement. This is possible by taking advantage of a feature of modern C++ called *user defined literals* that allow you to *produce objects of user-defined type by defining a user-defined suffix* much in the same way you append `U` to a integer literal to specify an unsigned value.

The first thing we'll do is define a user defined literal that produces a hash value that is calculated at compile time. Since this generates a hash value from the string it is possible to encounter collisions but that's dependant on the quality of the hash algorithm used. For our example we're going to use something simple. This following snippet defines a string literal with the suffix `_C` that generates our hash.

```
constexpr uint32_t djb2Hash(const char* str, int index = 0)
{
    return !str[index]
        ? 0x1505
        : (djb2Hash(str, index + 1) * 0x21) ^ str[index];
}

// Create a literal type for short-hand case strings
constexpr uint32_t operator"" _C(const char str[], size_t /*size*/)
{
    return djb2Hash(str);
}
```

Now every time the compiler sees a string literal in the format of `"Hello World"_C` it will produce a hash value and use that in place of the string.

Now we'll apply this to your existing code. First we'll separate the code that takes the user command from `cin` and make the given command all lower case.

```
std::string get_command()
{
    std::cout << "Input: ";

    std::string user_command;
    std::cin >> user_command;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::transform(
        user_command.begin(),
        user_command.end(),
        user_command.begin(),
        [](char ch) { return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(ch)); });

    return user_command;
}
```

There now that we can get an all lowercase command from the user we need to process that so we'll take your original set of `if`/`else` statements and turn them into a simple `switch`/`case` statement instead. Now since we can't actually use string literals in the `switch`/`case` statement we'll have to fudge a little bit and generate the hash value of the users command for the `switch` part of the code. We'll also take all of your commands and add the `_C` suffix to them so that the compiler automatically generates our hash values for us.

```
int main()
{
    bool main_loop = true;  //main loop enabler

    std::cout << "This is currency converter v1.0 (czk to eur and back)\n\n\n" << std::endl;

    while (main_loop)   //main loop for currency converter
    {
        const auto user_command(get_command());
        switch(djb2Hash(user_command.c_str()))
        {
        case "setbal"_C:
            std::cout << "Set balance command\n";
            break;

        case "addbal"_C:
            std::cout << "Add balance command\n";
            break;

        case "balance"_C:
            std::cout << "Get balance command\n";
            break;

        case "curstat"_C:
            std::cout << "Get current status command\n";
            break;

        case "help"_C:
            std::cout << "Get help command\n";
            break;

        case "exit"_C:
            main_loop = false;
            break;

        default:
            std::cout
                << "'" << user_command << "'"
                << "is not recognized as an internal or external command!\n"
                << "Type 'HELP' to see available commands.\n" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And there you have it. A totally wack solution! Now keep in mind that we're not really using strings in the `switch`/`case` statement, we're just hiding most of the details of generating hash values which are then used.

Comment: You’ll get collisions with any hash regardless of the algorithm used. (Sweet answer, BTW.)

Comment: How about checking the input with `isalpha()` and `islower()` beforehand and then compress the bits of the characters to a 64 bit integral? 5 bits per `char` allows to distinguish  up to12 characters long strings _without_ collision... ;-) (An upvote for the nice idea with the overloaded suffix. Would like to add one for the proof that `switch` _can_ be used with strings in C++...)

Comment: Nice answer 
As we are already going crazy: shouldn't it be possible to use the string pointer in the custom string literal as hash value? The compiler should take care of deduplicating the string occurrences, the pointers to the strings should therefore be perfectly unique (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/bxden6z74)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Well you can do it any number of ways including base32 and base64 stuffed into a 64 bit integer you just need to replace `djb2Hash` and provide `constexpr` versions of `isalpha` and `islower` with a `static_assert` on strings that exceed the max length (10 or 12 depending on base). If you come up with an alternative hash method feel free to expand on the answer and include it.

Comment: @Quxflux You can use the address of the string literal only if you can guarantee that the address of the string used at the point of `switch` is the same. This of course would limit you to how the strings can be used as they would *all* need to be visible compile time and you would not be able to source them from a file. You could of course search the string in a map for the address but that would defeat the motivation of the whole idea.